# Tomcat application wants to use proxy although no proxy is defined

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an application which is running on a tomcat 7.0.47 with java7. During processing it needs to connect to another application on the server and there is goes wrong with this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ProxyFactory.createSystemProxyConfiguration(ProxyFactory.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ProxyFactory.<init>(ProxyFactory.java:59)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.<init>(HTTPConduit.java:302)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getConduit(HTTPTransportFactory.java:248)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:228)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:94)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.prepare(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:61)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.prepareConduitSelector(ClientImpl.java:851)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:526)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:462)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:365)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:318)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:95)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
```

I checked the server and there is no system proxy defined. There are no proxy startup parameters defined for the tomcat. So I do not know how to the application come to the decision that it needs to use a proxy? The tomcat is running on a windows 2012 Server.

When I check the stack trace I could see that in the       org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ProxyFactory it seems that somewhere a proxydefinition was found, but where?

```
String proxyHost =SystemPropertyAction.getPropertyOrNull(HTTP_PROXY_HOST);
if (proxyHost != null) {
        // System is configured with a proxy, use it
```

Comment: Tomcat has no control over your application's desire to use a proxy. I think this is between your own environment and CXF.

Comment: Seems in somewhere returns the empty string instead of null

Comment: Just in case someone has the same problem. The bug was inside the cxf 2.5.9 version which I used. The bug is described here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4879 My solution was to upgrade to the fixed version 2.5.10